# LibGDX Tiled Map - Get MapObject ID

Tags: libgdx, tiled

I have a MapLayer with MapObjects and i want to know the ID of the MapObjects in this Layer, any idea how to get the ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID is stored as a property on the MapObject. You may be able to pass in `Integer.class` to `properties.get()` instead.

```
MapLayer objectLayer = model.Map.getLayers().get("Objects");

if(objectLayer != null){
    MapObjects objects = objectLayer.getObjects();

    for(MapObject mapObject : objects){

        MapProperties properties = mapObject.getProperties();

        String id = properties.get("id",String.class); 
    }       
}
```

That being said, I recommend you not use the ID value to identify objects on your map since Tiled does not give you control over this value. If the ID's ever change, then you will need to either edit your code or manually edit the .tmx file to correct this. Instead, you could add a custom property to the objects called "Tag" that will help you identify them.

Comment: Right, the ID isn't usually that useful and is more planned to be used by future versions of Tiled to make references between objects. Apart from adding custom properties, you can also use the built-in "name" and "type" properties of course.

Comment: Thanks! I was confused because the name and type and everything is available over getter but no ID. In my case its not so bad when the ids should change, i only need an integer that represents the object